# working control flow if the page has 2 html tags

Tags: php, html

regarding working control flow if the page has 2 html tags

```
<html>
 .....
  </html>
 <html>
  .....
 </html>
```

WHICH WOULD BE EXECUTED BOTH OR THE ONLY FIRST ONE....
I am working on a cs50 project in which when i call

```
   <?php
    dump($_SERVER);
    render("login_form.php", ["title" => "Log In"]);
    ?>
```

only dumps get executed whereas when

```
  <?php
    render("login_form.php", ["title" => "Log In"]);
    dump($_SERVER);
   ?>
```

both gets executed

the details of dump and render function are..

```
 function render($template, $values = [])
{
    // if template exists, render it
    if (file_exists("../templates/$template"))
    {
        // extract variables into local scope
        extract($values);

        // render header
        require("../templates/header.php");

        // render template
        require("../templates/$template");

        // render footer
        require("../templates/footer.php");
    }

    // else err
    else
    {
        trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

function dump

```
 function dump($variable)
{
    require("../templates/dump.php");
    exit;
}
```

the templates file are 
dump.php

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
    <title>dump</title>
</head>
```

similar are header.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <?php if (isset($title)): ?>
        <title>Mobi3: <?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?></title>
    <?php else: ?>
        <title>Mobi3</title>
    <?php endif ?>

    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="top">
            <a href="/"><img alt="C$50 Finance" src="/img/logo.gif"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="middle">

<body>
    <pre><?php print_r($variable); ?></pre>
</body>
```

footer.php

```
        <div id="bottom">
            Copyright &#169; M3shop
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is "having two sets of html tags" you are asking the wrong question. Regardless on which one is shown (which can also vary from browser to browser).

Comment: no the answer is not having two sets of html tags i am just asking according to which rule to decide which tag to process if the code has these types of 2 html tags